# How do you setup a key to repeat?

Tags: keyboard

I would like to setup a keybind to press and hold a key until I turn it back off again. Is there a way to do that?

Ex. Say I want to make the key 'g' repeat over and over until I toggle the keybind off, how can I do that?

I would be able to do that pretty easily on Windows using AutoHotKey, but I have no idea how to do something like that in Linux.

Thanks!

Comment: Something like an auto clicker?

Comment: @ADDB Not quite, I don't really need or want the mouse involved in any way. Just a keybind that will press and hold down a certain key until I toggle it off.

Comment: AutoClicker isn't always just mouse

Comment: @ADDB Ah, well, the more you know. Know of anything that can do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well AutoKey is the AutoHotKey pendant on Linux so

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

installs it for you. For information use the implemented handbook or search in the Internet